# Angular browser back button after redirect

Tags: angular, redirect, router, back-button

I've got a delegating component that does nothing else but resolving an object by the ID from a path (e.g. `/tournament/:id`) , detecting the tournament's type and forwarding (via `router.navigate(..)`) to another route (e.g. `/tournament/:id/league`)

The issue is that the browser back button would get back to the delegating component and show the empty template of my delegating component.

Are there other options to forward to another component than `router.navigate` considering the following:

1. Browser back button would not jump to the delegating component
2. The route `/tournament/:id/league` should be reflected in the browser URL

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceUrl: true` to skip the delegating component on back button press.

When navigating away from delegating component, just use something like this -

```
this.router.navigate(['A'], {
    replaceUrl: true
});
```

Comment: Thank You! this saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround, still hoping that someone comes up with something more sophisticated, as this snippet must be put into every component.

It is put into the constructor and checks if the new route is the one of the delegating component. If so, redirect to another route.

```
_location.subscribe(loc => {
  let routeOfDelegatingComponent = "....";
  if (loc.url === routeOfDelegatingComponent) {
    router.navigate(['/acustomroute']);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your delegating component, you can navigate to child component with the option to skip location change.

When you click the back button, the delegating component will not be activated.

```
  this.router.navigate([this.layoutData.tabs[0].tabName], {        
    skipLocationChange: true
  });
```